# Пагинация на Word Press

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой и решение не могу найти или возможно я что то не понимаю.
В общем сделал кастомную страницу и сделал ее статической главной. Пробую на ее вывести посты через WP_Quary но пагинация не работает а когда не делаю ее статической главной то работает и адресс показывает вот в таком виде:
site.com/home/page/2/
а когда делаю ее главной статической то показывает вот так но информация не подгружается
site.com/page/2

Пагинация вообще работает на статической странице если она главная?

Answer (score -1):

```
'paged' => get_query_var('page')          // Если страница главная
'paged' => get_query_var('paged')         // Вывод на второстепенной странице
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?